# AWS createfulfillmentorder "A create request already exists for MerchantFulfillmentOrderId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-mws, peddler

I'm running into an error when creating outbound fulfillment orders in MWS.
Every time I create a fulfillment using peddler, I get this response:

> A create request already exists for MerchantFulfillmentOrderId : xxxx

The fulfillment is created sucessfully in MWS but I get this error response regardless.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a new "Merchant Fulfillment Order Id" for every new request. It cannot already exist.